# How do I trigger or fire an event in chrome debugger?

Tags: google-chrome

I'd like to fire an event in the Chrome Debugger.  I'm not sure how to go about doing that.  Also, I'd like to know how to fire a custom event that takes arguments.

Answer (score 1):

1. Select the object in the DOM that hopefully listens to your event
2. Write the following in the console: `$0.dispatchEvent(new Event("mousemove"))`

To see the listeners use the tab "Event listeners".

Answer (score 0):

In the console:

1) Select the element

- For a particular element:  (i.e. selector = ".edit-list-button")

> var element = document.querySelector(selector)

- For the whole document

> var element = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]

2) Create the event

- Without arguments:

> var event = document.createEvent("Event")

- With arguments: (Where data can be any object including a simple string)

> var event = new CustomEvent(EVENT_NAME, { detail: DATA })

3) Initialize the event

> event.initEvent(EVENT_NAME, true, true)

4) Fire the event

> element.dispatchEvent(event)